# How do I append more objects to a JSON object without overwriting it?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object that looks like this -

```
0: {"": "1", company_name: ".", yearMonth: "1977-01-01", cumulative_raised: "0", rank: "1"}
1: {"": "2", company_name: ".comDominio", yearMonth: "1977-01-01", cumulative_raised: "0", rank: "2"}
2: {"": "3", company_name: ".FOX Networks", yearMonth: "1977-01-01", cumulative_raised: "0", rank: "3"}
3: {"": "4", company_name: "'Rock' Your Paper", yearMonth: "1977-01-01", cumulative_raised: "0", rank: "4"}
4: {"": "5", company_name: "( caravelo (", yearMonth: "1977-01-01", cumulative_raised: "0", rank: "5"}
5: {"": "6", company_name: "[24]7", yearMonth: "1977-01-01", cumulative_raised: "0", rank: "6"}
```

I'd like to make a JSON object that has each yearMonth and then a list of the companies in order of their rank that has information on their name and money raised. It would look like this -

```
{1977-01-01: {…}, 1977-02-01: {…}, 1977-03-01: {…}, 1977-04-01: {…}, 1977-05-01: {…}, …}
1977-01-01:
1: {name: ".FOX Networks", rank: "1", cumulative_raised: "20000"}
2: {name: "Blockcar", rank: "2", cumulative_raised: "10000"}
3: {name: "CHerry", rank: "3", cumulative_raised: "5000"}
4: {name: "TreesSimple", rank: "4", cumulative_raised: "2000"}
1977-02-01:
1: {name: "Blockcar", rank: "1", cumulative_raised: "30000"}
2: {name: "CHerry", rank: "2", cumulative_raised: "22000"}
3: {name: "Soundbus", rank: "3", cumulative_raised: "9000"}
4: {name: "Hopscotch", rank: "4", cumulative_raised: "5000"}
1977-03-01:
1: {name: "Honey", rank: "1", cumulative_raised: "30000"}
2: {name: "MangaRu", rank: "2", cumulative_raised: "22000"}
3: {name: "Hoss", rank: "3", cumulative_raised: "9000"}
4: {name: "Bread", rank: "4", cumulative_raised: "5000"}
```

This is the code I'm trying to do it with -

```
d3.csv("amount-raised-month.csv", function(error, csvdata) {
    if (error) throw error;

    csvdata.forEach(function(d) {
        companies[d.yearMonth] = {}
        companies[d.yearMonth][d.rank] = {"rank": d.rank, "name": d.company_name, "raised": d.cumulative_raised}
    }) })
```

The problem is that this code overwrites, instead of appending it. I wind up with just the last rank for each yearMonth.

```
 {1977-01-01: {…}, 1977-02-01: {…}, 1977-03-01: {…}, 1977-04-01: {…}, 1977-05-01: {…}, …}
    1977-01-01:
    4: {name: "TreesSimple", rank: "4", cumulative_raised: "2000"}
    1977-02-01:
    4: {name: "Hopscotch", rank: "4", cumulative_raised: "5000"}
    1977-03-01:
    4: {name: "Bread", rank: "4", cumulative_raised: "5000"}
```

How can I append the new JSON object each time instead of overwriting?

Comment: JSON is text (and the “JSON” included in the question is not JSON).. what you have there is an object graph (which is presumably later converted to JSON text). All the normal language rules apply for object (and thus object graph) mutability, independent of any JSON serialization.

Comment: So: 1) add an appropriate language tag 2) reduce the problem to a minimal example/data (eg. SSCCE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting your previous object with {}:

```
companies[d.yearMonth] = {}
```

Try this instead:

```
companies[d.yearMonth] = companies[d.yearMonth] || {};
```

or use an if statement:

```
if (!companies[d.yearMonth]) companies[d.yearMonth] = {};
```

Comment: Oh, I see. So it was going through and deleting all the info for that yearMonth and that's why I wound up with the last one.

Comment: @Cauder, exactly yes

Comment: That's like doing ` if (!companies.hasOwnProperty(d.yearMonth))`

Comment: @Cauder, It is checking if the value is truthy and if not it sets it to {}

Answer (score 0):

Create a Set based on the values of the original yearMonth attribute inside the original JSON.

Iterate this set. On each iteration, filter the original JSON comparing this yearMonth attribute. The filtered array will contain the companies by yearMonth. I cannot provide a code example right now, but I hope you get the idea.